# How can I combine meta_query queries?

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, meta-query

I'm trying to build combined meta_query queries but they don't work.
Any ideas how I can implement queries like the example below?

Thanks, Hinnerk

```
Array
(
    [relation] => AND
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => price
            [value] => 1000
            [type] => numeric
            [compare] => <=
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [relation] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => roomcount
                    [value] => 3
                    [type] => numeric
                    [compare] => >=
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => bathroomcount
                    [value] => 2
                    [type] => numeric
                    [compare] => >=
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show your query and how you build it and not the output of the Array?

Comment: @kaiser: Chip did it below

Comment: For future reference: it is much preferred that you include your *actual code* in your question, rather than `var_dump()` data or similar *output*.

Answer (score 4):

Using your constructed array, I *think* this is the correct syntax:

```
$meta_query_args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'price',
    'meta_value_num' => 1000,
    'meta_compare' => '<=',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'roomcount',
            'value' => 3,
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'bathroomcount',
            'value' => 2,
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    )
);

$realestate_meta_query = new WP_Query( $meta_query_args );
```

You might also try nesting `meta_query` one more level (though I don't know if that will work):

```
$meta_query_args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => 1000,
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'roomcount',
                'value' => 3,
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '>='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'bathroomcount',
                'value' => 2,
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '>='
            )
        )
    )
);

$realestate_meta_query = new WP_Query( $meta_query_args );
```

Comment: Your nested example is the one I've already tried (my array dump is the output of your example), but unfortunately it didn't work. The other example looks good for my very example, but besides price I actually have more keys to combine on that AND level.

Comment: @HinnerkAltenburg **Please** edit your question and show your actual query. It's annoying to ask multiple times. There can be that many things that don't work or give unexpected output just because there's a single char different. Copypasteedit for the rescue...